# nested query in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I am new for PHP/mysql where I use them as backend for flutter app .
I have 4 tables post,user,likes,comments and would like to filter the data of a post and the related likes and comments as well the post owner data(user) by a post property called category_name and its value is passed via a variable called "filter"

I have tried the nested query as following:

```
 <?php
$filter = "PMS";

if($filter=="All"){
   $sql= "SELECT users.*,post.*,COUNT(likes.user_id) as qty 
    ,COUNT(comments.Comment_owner_id) as comments FROM 
     likes JOIN post ON likes.post_id=post.id JOIN users ON 
     users.id=post.user_id JOIN comments ON 
     post.id=comments.post_id 
      GROUP BY post.id";

 }else{
   $sql= "SELECT test.* FROM (SELECT users.*,post.* 
    ,COUNT(likes.user_id) as qty ,COUNT(comments.Comment_owner_id) 
      as comments FROM post ->
    JOIN likes ON likes.post_id=post.id JOIN users ON 
    users.id=post.user_id JOIN comments ON post.id=comments.post_id   
    AS test GROUP BY post.id) WHERE test.category_name='$filter'";

   //execute the query

  $res= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

   //convert it to an list

  $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if($posts){
    echo json_encode($posts);
  }else{
   echo "error";
  }


   ?>
```

but it does not work where I got the following message

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_all(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\blog\data\postAll.php:32 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\blog\data\postAll.php(32): mysqli_fetch_all(false, 1) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\blog\data\postAll.php on line 32
```

, have you any suggestions ?

Comment: Anhd "it does not work" means what, actually? Do you get an error? Which? Do you get unexpected data? What? Did you implement error handling? Does it indicate an issue with the query? What if you execute the query directly in a mysql console? What does your http server's error log file say?

Comment: Do you mean list posts and multiple comments in each post? Just like this?

Comment: Your query makes no sense. It contains incomplete GROUP BY, hence it can produce indefinite unpredictable output. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and ensure.

Comment: Plz provide details, how toh Table looks like and when you some code it should properly indent. Otherwise it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Do you mean the variable filter should be $filter?$sql= "SELECT test.* FROM (SELECT users.*,post.* ,COUNT(likes.user_id) as qty ,COUNT(comments.Comment_owner_id) as comments FROM post 
JOIN likes ON likes.post_id=post.id JOIN users ON users.id=post.user_id JOIN comments ON post.id=comments.post_id   GROUP BY post.id
) AS test  WHERE Test.category_name=".$filter;

Comment: Please add the exact errors you are receiving so that users on SO can help you.

Comment: The error showing about `mysqli_fetch_all()` but you did not show the `mysqli_xxx` functions call.

Comment: I want to filter the posts by its category_name value which is passed from the user through a variable called filter and then grab all the related likes comments post_owner data from the other tables

Comment: [`mysqli_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) can return `false` or result set. In case it is false, show the error message like [`mysqli_error($conn)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) could help that why the SQL statement error. This is very useful for some invalid SQL statement. Use `if (false === $res) {echo mysqli_error($conn); exit();}` after `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Remove `->` from your query

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the solution could be so simple

```
$sql="SELECT post.*,users.*,COUNT(likes.user_id) AS likes from post JOIN  users ON post.user_id=users.id LEFT JOIN likes ON post.id=likes.post_id WHERE post.category_name = '$filter' GROUP BY post.id";
```

It worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are laravel developer
you can use laravel package https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset